# C# MVC redirect action to same action in new Server or new URL with session & cookies information

Tags: c#, session, cookies, model-view-controller, session-cookies

I have a situation where I need to redirect an action called on one server to another server.

I have 2 servers running the same code with different urls.
The purpose of having additional url is to direct the heavy traffic on other server.
Now I got a call to my controller on server A and I want to redirect it to the same action on Server B.

I am trying something like the following:

```
public ActionResult MethodName(long id)
        {
            if (redirect)
            {
                return Redirect(https://ServerB/Controller/MethodName/" + id.ToString());

            }
}
```

The issue here is that when the request lands on Server B, it lands with its own session variable that does not match with the original request's and so it fails there.
Also, I am using the session using cookies.

I tried using the HttpWebRequest and adding all the cookies in the Cookie container object, but that also did not work.

Can anyone please help me here and put me in the right direction.

I'll provide more information if required.

Comment: In order to share session state, You'll need to use a shared SQL server DB to store the session state in, Everything else should just work then. There's plenty of solutions to load balance like this without implementing it at application level though - But they too would require a shared session DB

Comment: Can we do anything apart from this? I cannot change my Session state to SQL

Comment: I'ts going to be very hard and hacky without a shared session database. That doesn't need to be SQL server, but it'll require some sort of shared storage. The SQL server implementation is the only one I know off the top of my head that'll do that, but I'd bet there's other implementation for Redis / Mongo ect you could look at